# Tensorflow 2: How to use stack of dense layers in keras functional API?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a model, where I want to give no_of_dense_layers as a parameter and expecting from function to create dense layers in the loop.

Creating dense layers in the loop is not an issue, My problem is how to pass values in stack of dense layers in Keras?

let's say I want 3 dense layers :

```
def get_layers(no_of_dense_layers  , dense_size):
    return [tf.keras.layers.Dense(dense_size[i], activation = 'elu', 
                                      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=200)) for i in range(no_of_dense_layers)]
```

Now if I want to use Sequential API I can do like this:

```
perceptron = tf.keras.Sequential(get_layers(3,[1000,500,300]))
```

But if I want to use functional API, How to achieve the same functionality?

Something like this:

```
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1024), dtype='float32', name='embedding_input')

## This layer should pass input of first denselayer >> dense_layer2 >> dense_layer3
   dense_layers = get_layers(3,[1000,500,300])


# Above layer should be equal to : 
# x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000)
# x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(500)
# x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(300)


# Then simply pass the output of all three dense layers to classification last layer

# classification_layer 

cls_layer  = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation= 'elu')(dense_layers)
```

What I have tried:

```
first_layer = dense_layers[0](input_layer)
for k in dense_layers[1:]:
    print(k(first_layer))
```

Is there any other method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a possibility:

```
def get_layers(inp, no_of_dense_layers, dense_size):
    
    for i in range(no_of_dense_layers):
    
        x = Dense(dense_size[i])(inp)
        inp = x
        
    return x

inp = Input((1024,))
x = get_layers(inp, 3, [1000,500,300])    
out = Dense(1)(x)

m = Model(inp, out)
m.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_45 (InputLayer)        [(None, 1024)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_88 (Dense)             (None, 1000)              1025000   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_89 (Dense)             (None, 500)               500500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_90 (Dense)             (None, 300)               150300    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_91 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 301
```